# Apache процесс не умирает после отключения клиента, если RabbitMQ

Tags: php, apache, docker, rabbitmq

Я все еще пытаюсь использовать [Server Side Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) в моем проекте. (Это как Long Polling на стероидах)

Пример, который приведен под подзаголовком "[Sending events from the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)" работает прекрасно. Через несколько секунд, после того как клиент (браузер) отключается от сервера, Apache процесс успешно умирает, завершая всю работу PHP скрипта.

НО! Если к этой всей схеме подключить [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib), Apache продолжает жить вечно (или до таймаута), пока я не убью процесс, перезапущу сервер или Docker контейнер.

[connection_aborted](http://php.net/function.connection-aborted) и [connection_status](http://php.net/function.connection-status) не работают от слова совсем. `connection_aborted` всегда возвращает `0` and `connection_status` возвращает `CONNECTION_NORMAL` даже после отключения клиента. Прикол весь в том, что это происходит ТОЛЬКО вместе с RabbitMQ. Без RMQ эти функции возвращают правильные значения (магия? баг?)

`ignore_user_abort(false)` не работает тоже. Процесс продолжает жить долго и счастливо выполняя всю свою работу и сжирая все ресурсы сервера.

Пример кода:

```
class RequestsRabbit
{
    protected $rabbit;

    /** @var AMQPChannel */
    protected $channel;

    public $exchange = 'requests.events';

    public function __construct(AbstractConnection $rabbit)
    {
        $this->rabbit = $rabbit;
    }

    public function getChannel()
    {
        if ($this->channel === null) {
            $channel = $this->rabbit->channel();

            $channel->exchange_declare($this->exchange, 'fanout', false, false, false);

            $this->channel = $channel;
        }

        return $this->channel;
    }

    public function send($message)
    {
        $channel = $this->getChannel();

        $message = json_encode($message);

        $channel->basic_publish(new AMQPMessage($message), $this->exchange);
    }

    public function subscribe(callable $callable)
    {
        $channel = $this->getChannel();

        list($queue_name) = $channel->queue_declare('', false, false, true, false);

        $channel->queue_bind($queue_name, $this->exchange);

        $callback = function (AMQPMessage $msg) use ($callable) {
            call_user_func($callable, json_decode($msg->body));
        };

        $channel->basic_consume($queue_name, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

        while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
            if (connection_aborted()) {
                break;
            }

            try {
                $channel->wait(null, true, 5);
            } catch (AMQPTimeoutException $exception) {
            }
        }

        $channel->close();
        $this->rabbit->close();
    }
}
```

> Если посмотреть внимательно на код можно увидеть, *(1)* если `connection_aborted` является истинным, то цикл прерывается, и *(2)* специально выставлен timeout в пять секунд (`wait(null, true, 5)`), чтобы, если долго нет каких либо событий внутри RMQ, а клиент уже отключился (`connection_aborted`), процесс был завершен. Но это не работает, так как `connection_aborted` никогда не бывает истинным :(

Если по порядку:

- Браузер настраивает SSE подключение к серверу. `var es = new EventSource(url);`
- Apache спаунит новый процесс, чтобы обработать запрос от клиента (это нормально, пока что все ок)
- PHP генерирует новую очередь у RabbitMQ и подключается к ней.
- Браузер отключается от сервер `es.close()`
- Apache2 не убивает процесс -- он остается жить как есть. Очередь тоже не удаляется (естественно, ею же пользуется не убитый процесс). Если я N раз переподключусь к серверу, заспаунится N процессов и создастся N очередей.
- Естественно, так как проблема со стороны сервера, никакие действия с браузером не помогают.

Выглядит как баг PHP или Apache. Не уверен, что какая-то библиотека может повлиять на встроенные функции `connection_aborted` и `connection_status`.

Что используется:

- Последние Docker и docker-compose
- [php:7.1.12-apache или php:5.6-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) образ. Ошибка воспроизводится на обеих версиях.

Гугление особо ничего не дало. Нашел [вот этот старейший баг](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30301). Неужели c 2004 не исправили?!

Кажется, что единственный вариант -- ping-pong. Или более низкий timeout. Проблема в том, что SSE -- однонаправленный поток (сервер => клиент). Поэтому придется либо все таки переходить на WS, либо заморачиваться пинг-понгом через другой скрипт..

Немного скриншотов:

[image: RabbitMQ queues]

[image: Processes]

Пожалуйста, помогите мне решить эту проблему или найти обходное решение. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Вы можете использовать альтернативный механизм? Потому что SSE, мягко говоря, странная штука.

Comment: @etki На самом деле SSE очень удобная штука. Особенно, в плане поддержания и разработки. Но, учитывая, как PHP себя плохо ведет, придется выбрать, наверное, WS. К тому же есть такая классная штука websocketd, которая упрощает создание WS сервисов на чем угодно (хоть на bash)